# How to replace part of a string in one row with a word from another row?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am trying to fill in the template from a row with words from another column of the same row of a dataframe in R.

Here is an example of what I'm looking to do:

```
x <- data.frame("replacement" = c("two", "ten"), 
"text" = c("we had <replacement> books", "we had <replacement> books"),
"result" = c("we had two books", "we had ten books"))
```

I tried using gsub, but it replaces all words instead of one:

```
x$result <- gsub("\\<.+?\\>", x$replacement, x$text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` as the documentation (`?str_replace`) says

> Vectorised over string, pattern and replacement.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
x %<>%
  mutate(result = str_replace(text, "<replacement>", as.character(replacement)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) How do I save it in the column "result"?

Comment: @alinaz Just change the 'text' to 'result' in `mutate`

Comment: @alinaz To make it more faster, you can wrap with `fixed("<replacement>")`

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can also try:

```
x %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(result = sub("<replacement>", replacement, text, fixed = TRUE))
```